# How to display the selected image in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I wanted to upload images and display the image which was chosen, How to display the image after choosing. this is my code, help me display the image, I made the function to post the image, I can post multiple images in one click but i can't display the image to preview before upload , i try to use file reader but cannot display and upload.

```js
   
  const [pImg, setPImg] = useState([]);
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

 
  const addImg = (ImagesPostDto) => {
    const data2 = new FormData();
    [...ImagesPostDto].forEach((Images) => {
      data2.append("ImagesPostDto", Images);
    });
    Axios.post(`/shop/${shopID}/Product/${pID}/Images`, data2)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          setMessage({
            data: `${res.data.MESSAGE}`,
            type: "alert-success",
          });
          onShowAlert();
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setMessage({
          data: `${err.response.data.MESSAGE}`,
          type: "alert-danger",
        });
        setLoading(false);
        onShowAlert();
      });
  };

  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const ProductImg = e.target.files;
    setPImg(ProductImg);
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = () => {
  setPImg(ProductImg);
  setImages(reader.result);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(ProductImg);
  };

  const handleProductSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    addImg(pImg);
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      
   
        <Form>
          <p>
            <Label htmlFor="file">Upload images</Label>
            <input
              type="file"
              id="file"
              onChange={handleImageChange}
              accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg"
              multiple
            />
          </p>
        </Form>
        <div className="">
          {/* {images.length > 0 ? (
            <div>
              {images.map((image) => (
                <p>
                  <img src={images} alt="" />
                </p>
              ))}
            </div>
          ) : null} */}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to render images then, create ObjectURL from files array and set the images State then it should work fine. I have commented the code related to API call so that we can focus on rendering the selected images.You can just simply copy this code and paste it in CodeSandBox it should work fine Here is your code a bit modified:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [pImg, setPImg] = useState([]);
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  // const addImg = (ImagesPostDto) => {
  //   const data2 = new FormData();
  //   [...ImagesPostDto].forEach((Images) => {
  //     data2.append("ImagesPostDto", Images);
  //   });
  //   Axios.post(`/shop/${shopID}/Product/${pID}/Images`, data2)
  //     .then((res) => {
  //       if (res.status === 200) {
  //         setMessage({
  //           data: `${res.data.MESSAGE}`,
  //           type: "alert-success"
  //         });
  //         onShowAlert();
  //       }
  //     })
  //     .catch((err) => {
  //       setMessage({
  //         data: `${err.response.data.MESSAGE}`,
  //         type: "alert-danger"
  //       });
  //       setLoading(false);
  //       onShowAlert();
  //     });
  // };

  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("event", e);
    const ProductImg = [...e.target.files];
    const images = ProductImg.map((image) => URL.createObjectURL(image));
    console.log("images", images);
    setImages(images);
  };

  // const handleProductSubmit = (event) => {
  //   event.preventDefault();
  //   addImg(pImg);
  // };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <p>
          <label htmlFor="file">Upload images</label>
          <input
            type="file"
            id="file"
            onChange={handleImageChange}
            accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg"
            multiple
          />
        </p>
      </form>
      <div className="">
        {images.length > 0 && (
          <div>
            {images.map((image, index) => (
              <p key={index}>
                <img src={image} alt="" />
              </p>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the Images from GET API and set the response in setImages than it will show right now the images variable is empty array.

Comment: i wanted to display the previee of the image before upload the image

Answer (score 0):

As far I can understand your requirement, you need to preview the Images Either when you have selected or After uploaded.

What you can do is, whenever you are preparing the FormData or at the time of change event, you can store each selected file's ObjectURL in another state and Easily can display these images via the State.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).